# LINQ to return subset of data grouped into an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of people and I'd like to use LINQ (query syntax) to get an anonymous type containing all the firstnames and all the second names.

If I were to use a foreach:

```
var firstNames = new HashSet<string>();
var secondNames = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (Person p in ListOfPersons)
{
  firstNames.Add(p.firstName);
  secondNames.Add(p.secondName);
}
```

What is an equivalent and efficient LINQ statement that returns an anonymous type? Eg, allNames.FirstNames and allNames.SecondNames.

EDIT: when I say efficient, I mean that it loops over the ListOfPersons once, as in the foreach example above.

EDIT 2: the names should be distinct; I changed the List<> to HashSet<> in the foreach example

Comment: Question - if you are returning an anonymous type, why do you need 2 variables, `firstNames` and `secondNames`?

Comment: Are you after all the names or just the distinct names?

Comment: @Enigmativity good point, yes, distinct names

Comment: @cyrus - Then your efficiency goes out of the window for the iteration. Using **Atomosk**'s solution, on some data from a real-world database (that has been brought into memory), I can extract the names is 10.5ms, but to make them distinct it takes me a further 41.3ms. Iterating the original source twice to produce the distinct lists only takes 48.3ms. This is a case when iterating twice is better than once.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to iterate ListOfPersons twice the only way I see it in linq is

```
var firstNames = new List<string>();
var secondNames = new List<string>();

persons.Aggregate(Tuple.Create(firstNames, secondNames), (tuple, person) =>
{
    tuple.Item1.Add(person.firstName);
    tuple.Item2.Add(person.secondName);
    return tuple;
});
```

but I think foreach is much better.

Comment: This will be much slower than iterating twice.

Comment: Actually, this isn't slower. In this case it's not creating temporary variables so it is faster.

Comment: @Enigmativity It depends on what persons is. Not every `IEnumerable` is a `List`. Maybe persons's `GetEnumerator()` performs some very complex logic. Or maybe it produces different results for 2 different calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var AnonList = ListOfPersons.Select(x=> new {firstname = x.firstName, secondname = x.secondName});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var allNames = new
{
    firstNames = new List<string>(),
    secondNames = new List<string>()
};

listOfPersons.ForEach( p => 
{
    allNames.firstNames.Add( p.firstName );
    allNames.secondNames.Add( p.secondName );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nameList = from l in ListOfPersons
               select new { FirstName = l.Firstname, Surname = l.Surname};
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter intuitively, this is the most efficient:

```
var names = new
{
    firstNames = ListOfPersons.Select(x => x.firstName).Distinct().ToList(),
    secondNames = ListOfPersons.Select(x => x.secondName).Distinct().ToList(),
};
```

It turns out that iterating over the list twice is more efficient that concocting a method to iterate over it once as many more temporary variables are created. I've done speed tests on this kind of thing and iterating over the list multiple times wins.

Comment: fwiw if you look at my original answer I had pretty much the exact same thing (see edit history) and was down voted because of the double iteration...